# how to select all li with a specific class using css selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have an unordered list with 2 levels, and i would like to hide "first level submenus" and show them only when "first level" li is hover.

here,s the code :

```
<ul>
      <li>first level</li>
               <ul>
                  <li>first level submenuitem 1</li>
                  <li>first level submenuitem 2</li>
               </ul>
      <li>another list item</li>
</ul>
```

how can i do that with pure CSS selectors ?

Comment: FWIW: Your hierarchy is incorrect: `UL` cannot be child of another `UL`. You should place it inside `LI`.

Comment: You need to actually give them a class in order to select by that specific class...

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
ul ul {display: none;}

ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

If you might have more than two levels then you might wanna be more specific, for say:

```
ul li > ul {display: none;}

ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gssVQ/)**

Comment: This requires that the markup is correct, as in the code example. In the code in the question, the submenu `ul` needs to be moved inside an `li` of the outer list.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
ul li:first-child:hover ul li {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use jQuery

```
<ul>
      <li class="show">first level</li>
           <ul class="child" style="display: none;">
              <li>first level submenuitem 1</li>
              <li>first level submenuitem 2</li>
           </ul>
  <li class="show">another list item</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(".show").hover(function() {
     $(this).find('.child').show();

     });
</script>
```